# Playframework Scala Async controller for JSON request

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I am trying to write an async PlayFramework controller that receives a POST request and creates a new object in the database:

```
  def register = Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { request =>
    val businessInfoResult = request.body.validate[BusinessInfo]
    businessInfoResult.fold(errors =>{
      BadRequest(Json.obj("status"-> "Error", "message"->JsError.toJson(errors))) //Error on this line
    }, businessInfo=> {
      //save the object
      Ok(Json.obj("status" ->"OK", "message" -> ("Place '"+ businessInfo.businessName +"' saved.") )) //Error on this line

    })
  }
```

However, it keeps throwing the error below:

```
reference to Json is ambiguous; it is imported twice in the same scope by import play.libs.Json and import play.mvc.BodyParser.Json AsyncController.scala
```

The errors are thrown at line 108 and 105 which correspond to lines commented with `//Error on this line` above (lines with BadRequest(..) and Ok(..))

How do I fix this issue? I can using new JsValue(Map(..)) but was wondering if there's any other way.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `Json`, you probably want to call `play.libs.Json`. The problem here is that, considering the imports in your file, you have two objects / classes called `Json` and the compiler can't choose which one it should use. Calling `play.libs.Json`, you'll give the compiler enough information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one or more aliases in your imports:

```
import play.libs.Json
import play.mvc.BodyParser.{Json => JsonParser}
```

`JsonParser` is just an example. You can use anything you like as long as it's unique within the file.

Instead of writing `Json` (for `play.mvc.BodyParser.Json`) you could now use the alias `JsonParser`.

But are you sure you even need to import `play.mvc.BodyParser.Json`? Because you don't seem to use it.